# I can't assign a username and password when I generate a wcf proxy using svcutil?

Tags: wcf

If I create a new project and add a wcf service reference to it,I can use the client it generates to assign the username and password to ClientCredentials, but if I create the proxy using svcutil.exe and the wsdl, the proxy code it generates doesn't allow me to set the username and password.

Comment: Why doesn't it let you set the credentials? Doesn't the generated class inherit from ClientBase<T>, which has a ClientCredentials property?

Comment: Carlo, for some strange reason it worked this time. The only thing I remember from last time is that I did not use the /t:code switch when using svcutil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just work; generated proxies inherit from `ClientBase<T>`, which has a ClientCredentials property. If this happens to you again, please post the generated class signature, and we can look at it.

Comment: Ok, great thanks, I do have a couple a couple other questions, but I will post it in another question.